# How to use sp_tracing?

Tags: runtime, frame, substrate-node, modules

When I walk through the sp_tracing documents, it's an overview and does not show us how to use it

I have some questions about sp_tracing:

- How to use it? What command that we run it? (Debug Mode?)
- What is it different with Debug https://docs.substrate.io/test/debug/

Comment: Well, there are examples for the two macros the crate provides. [`within_span`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_tracing/macro.within_span.html) and [`enter_span`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_tracing/macro.enter_span.html). But I think is an interesting question overall. Upvoting.

Comment: Where do you want to use it? In a pallet (runtime) or the node?

Comment: usually in node(native) part